# CakePHP 3.x - hasMany through association - find

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Assuming I have exactly the setup as in CookBook here:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

```
class StudentsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Courses', [
            'through' => 'CourseMemberships',
        ]);
    }
}

class CoursesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Students', [
            'through' => 'CourseMemberships',
        ]);
    }
}

class CoursesMembershipsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Students');
        $this->belongsTo('Courses');
    }
}

Student BelongsToMany Course
Course BelongsToMany Student

id | student_id | course_id | days_attended | grade
```

How should I construct the query to find Courses for given Student that he has Grade == "A"?

```
$query = $this->Courses->find('all')
    ->contain(['CourseMemberships'])
    ->where(['CourseMemberships.student_id' => $student['id'], 'CourseMemberships.grade' => 'A']);
```

This will not work. How should I write it?

Comment: This code triggers error: "Courses is not associated with CourseMembers"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Normally you'd use [**matching**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data), but the ORM doesn't seem to support matching on join table "associations", as they are not "real" associations at that point (you may want to [**suggest that as an enhancement**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues)), they are being added at a later point.

### `matching()` workaround

What works is using `matching()` and `where()` on the outer query, ie

```
$query = $this->Courses
    ->find('all')

     // contain needs to use `Students` instead (the `CourseMemberships`
     // data can be found in the `_joinData` property of the tag),
     // or dropped alltogether in case you don't actually need that
     // data in your results
    ->contain(['Students'])

     // this will do the magic
    ->matching('Students')

    ->where([
        'CourseMemberships.student_id' => $student['id'],
        'CourseMemberships.grade' => 'A'
    ]);
```

This will join in the `students` table as well as the `courses_students` join table using the `CourseMemberships` alias, like

```
INNER JOIN
    students Students ON 1 = 1
INNER JOIN
    courses_students CourseMemberships ON (
        Courses.id = (CourseMemberships.course_id)
        AND Students.id = (CourseMemberships.student_id)
    )
```

and so the conditions can be applied. That feels like a not very nice workaround tough.

### Use an additional association (probably the better approach)

Another option would be to add another, explicit association (as kind of mentioned @AtaboyJosef), ie a `hasMany` association for the join table (this would be done automatically at a later point, but as already mentioned, it's too late for `matching()`).

Note that this will require the join table to be named `course_memberships`!

```
class CoursesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Students', [
            'joinTable' => 'course_memberships',
            'through' => 'CourseMemberships',
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('CourseMemberships', [
            'foreignKey' => 'course_id'
        ]);
    }
}
```

That way you can use matching on the `CourseMemberships` association

```
$query = $this->Courses
    ->find('all')
    // with this solution you can also use contain for `CourseMemberships`
    ->contain(['CourseMemberships'])
    ->matching('CourseMemberships', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $query) use ($student) {
        return $query->where([
            'CourseMemberships.student_id' => $student['id'],
            'CourseMemberships.grade' => 'A'
        ]);
    });
```

which should create a query like

```
INNER JOIN course_memberships CourseMemberships ON (
    CourseMemberships.student_id = 1 
    AND CourseMemberships.grade = 'A' 
    AND Course.id = (CourseMemberships.course_id)
)
```

which might be a little more efficient as it requires less selects.

Comment: ad. "matching() workaround" - I added "matching(...)" line but I still get - "Courses is not associated with CourseMemberships"

Comment: @ZbigniewLedwoń That's because the `contain()` shouldn't be there (or use `Tags` instead) in that case, I've overlooked that. I'll update my answer...

Comment: I removed `contain()` and it worked like a charm. But now I get 2 warnings I do not understand:  `Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression::_addConditions() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites/giftbooking/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Expression/QueryExpression.php on line 124 and defined [CORE/src/Database/Expression/QueryExpression.php, line 503]`    
`Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [CORE/src/Database/Expression/QueryExpression.php, line 509]`

Comment: @ZbigniewLedwoń Yeah, that's a bug that should be fixed in the next release **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7102** If you can't wait you can use  `dev-master` until it's available.

Comment: @ZbigniewLedwoń Or use the second solution instead, it's probably the better one anyways.

Comment: I was finally able to figure out what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: `// this will do the magic`. This finally did the magic after long hours :)

Comment: followed the example as scenario is perfectly same. only issue i have is,it is giving undefined variable"$student['id']".  how can i pass "$student['id']".

Comment: @pkd The example was missing a `use` construct... I've updated the answer. You may also want to read about how anonymous functions/closures work: **http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php**.

Comment: got the solution. pass $student['id'] using 'use' keyword

Answer (score 0):

**`through`** Allows you to provide a either the name of the Table instance you want used on the join table, or the instance itself. This makes customizing the join table keys possible, and allows you to customize the behavior of the pivot table.

Define a more specific relationship using array syntax:

```
class StudentsTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Courses', [
            'joinTable' => 'courses',
            'through' => 'CourseMemberships',
        ]);
    }
}

class CoursesTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Students', [
            'joinTable' => 'students',
            'through' => 'CourseMemberships',
        ]);
    }
}

class CoursesMembershipsTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Students', [
            'foreignKey' => 'student_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',        // OR specify the type 
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Courses', [
            'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Be sure that you have tables `courses`, `students`, and `course_memberships`.

Now run the code:

```
$query = $this->Courses->find('all')
    ->contain(['CourseMemberships'])
    ->where(['CourseMemberships.student_id' => $student['id'], 'CourseMemberships.grade' => 'A']);
```

Well, I'm affraid if you really need something related with the [**`HasMany Associations`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations).