# Innerjoin with associated tables always ends up with "not associated with" error

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, model-associations

I want to make this query (the `$ownerQuery` is the relevant part here):

```
$searchQuery = $this->Tickets
            ->find('byStatus',['status' =>$status])
            ->find('byTitle',['queries' => $queries]);
$ownerQuery = $searchQuery
            ->innerJoinWith(
                'Projects.ProjectsTickets', function($q) use( &$userId){
                    return $q->where(['Tickets.id' => 'ProjectsTickets.ticket_id'])
                             ->where(['Projects.id' => 'ProjectsTickets.project_id'])
                             ->where(['Projects.user_id' => $userId]);
                }
             );
```

Or something that achieves the same effect, however every variation of this I have tried ends up with a not associated with error.

Here are my associations:

ProjectsTicketsTable:

```
class ProjectsTicketsTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('projects_tickets');
        $this->displayField('project_id');
        $this->primaryKey(['project_id', 'ticket_id']);

        //$this->belongsTo('Projects', [
        //    'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
        //    'joinType' => 'INNER'
        //]);
        //$this->belongsTo('Tickets', [
        //    'foreignKey' => 'ticket_id',
        //    'joinType' => 'INNER'
        //]);

        $this->belongsTo('Projects');
        $this->belongsTo('Users');
    }
}
```

ProjectsTable:

```
class ProjectsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('projects');
        $this->displayField('title');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Tags', [
            'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        //$this->belongsToMany('Tickets', [
        //    'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
        //    'targetForeignKey' => 'ticket_id',
        //    'joinTable' => 'projects_tickets'
        //]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Tickets', [
            'through' => 'ProjectTickets',
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinTable' => 'projects_users'
        ]);
    }
}
```

TicketsTable:

```
class TicketsTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('tickets');
        $this->displayField('title');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        //$this->belongsToMany('Projects', [
        //    'foreignKey' => 'ticket_id',
        //    'targetForeignKey' => 'project_id',
        //    'joinTable' => 'projects_tickets'
        //]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Projects', [
            'through' => 'ProjectTickets',
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Comments', [
            'foreignKey' => 'ticket_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'comment_id',
            'joinTable' => 'tickets_comments'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'ticket_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinTable' => 'tickets_users'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with the associations or the query that I could fix?

**EDIT:** By changing the associations like the link NDM provided I did manage to get rid of the 'no association errors' however all queries trying to combine columns from tables always result in 0 results.

For example this search that should return all tickets (because all of them are in the ProjectsTickets table) is returning nothing:

```
$ownerQuery = $searchQuery
            ->innerJoinWith(
                'Projects.ProjectsTickets', function($q) use( &$userId){
                    return $q->where(['Tickets.id' => 'ProjectsTickets.ticket_id']);
                             //->where(['Projects.id' => 'ProjectsTickets.project_id'])
                             //->where(['Projects.user_id' => $userId]);
                }
             );
```

If I however uncomment only the user line it is correctly displaying all results.

**EDIT 2:** While the association workaround works the matching one doesnt wich proves a bit problematic. For example if I want to do this query without having to make an association between Tickets and ProjectsUsers:

```
    $adminQuery = $searchQuery
        ->distinct()
        ->matching('ProjectsUsers')
        ->where([
                'Tickets.id = ProjectsTickets.ticket_id',
                'ProjectsTickets.project_id = ProjectsUsers.project_id',
                'ProjectsUsers.user_id' => $userId,
                'ProjectsUsers.role = Admin'
            ]);
```

This is still resulting in `Tickets is not associated with ProjectsUsers`

Comment: Looks like the same problem as **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643906/cakephp-3-x-hasmany-through-association-find** to me. Note that `innerJoinWith()` works just like `matching()`, the only difference is that the match will not be included in the results.

Comment: @ndm Hey I tried that and the no matching errors are gone however now the query isn't returning any results so I think I am still doing something wrong here.

Comment: Oh wow I figured it out, theres a different syntax if you want to compare two columns.

Comment: You're coming up with all kinds of new stuff... as mentioned in the linked answer, you cannot match on join tables that way. Take a closer look at the code example, it matches on the actual existing association, and the join table is being included that way automatically. The cleaner approach however would be to create an additional association.